# Qt emit form class A to slot in class B

Tags: qt, signals-slots

I'm trying to make a log window for my Gui app.

I have classes named sql and MyService

How do i build and emit signal from class sql to update MyService log window?

in main.cpp:

```
    MyService myService;
    sql mySql;
    QObject::connect(mySql, SIGNAL(updateMyLog(QString(msg))),myService, 
    SLOT(updateMyLog(QString(msg))));
```

**EDIT:**
I forgot Q_OBJECT in my sql class
and the error dosnt show any more

```
error: C2665: 'QObject::connect' : 
none of the 3 overloads could convert all the argument types
```

**EDIT2:**
my slot for updateMyLog is:

```
public slots:
void updateMyLog(QString logmessage);
```

and i get different error:

```
QObject::connect: No such signal sql::updateMyLog(QString msg)
```

Comment: Could you write your MyService 'updateMyLog' declaration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does it work if you write it like this?

```
QObject::connect(&mySql, SIGNAL(updateMyLog(QString)), &myService, 
SLOT(updateMyLog(QString)));
```

Please note that you should pass pointers as the first and third parameters. As `myService` is not a pointer, you should get the memory address where it is allocated (a pointer to it).

Answer (score 0):

its seems i should do this:

```
QObject::connect(&mySql, SIGNAL(updateMyLog(QString)),&myService,
                 SLOT(updateMyLog(QString)));
```